# Temporary couchdb view of documents with doc_id matching regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, couchdb

I have a couchdb database containing different types of documents. Unfortunately some of those documents were generated without a `type` field, so I can not easily distinguish them. I want to add that `type` field now. Fortunately the `doc_id` has also this information, and I want to use it to perform the update.

What I would like is to create a temporary view of the documents whose `doc_id` matches a certain regex, let's say:

```
^user_
```

Is there a way to define such a map function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as expected:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc._id.match(/^user_.*$/)) {
    emit(null, doc);
  }
}
```

Have you even tried anything?

Comment: My syntax was completely off. Thanks.